# how to make this in doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to make a sql query like this,

```
UPDATE org_mapping SET is_active = 1 WHERE (org_id = ? AND service_provider_id = ? )OR (org_id = ? AND service_provider_id = ?)
```

I tried this but its now working:

```
$q = $qb->update('Organization\Entity\OrgMapping', 'om')
        ->set('om.active', $qb->expr()->literal($isActive))
        ->where('om.organization = ?1')->andWhere('om.serviceProvider = ?2')
        ->orWhere('om.organization = ?2')->andWhere('om.serviceProvider = ?1')
        ->setParameter(1, $organizationId)
        ->setParameter(2, $hspId)
        ->getQuery();
```

When i am running, i am getting the following query:

```
UPDATE org_mapping SET is_active = 1 WHERE ((org_id = ? AND service_provider_id = ?) OR org_id = ?) AND service_provider_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
->orWhere('om.organization = ?2')->andWhere('om.serviceProvider = ?1')
```

With

```
->orWhere('om.organization = ?2 AND om.serviceProvider = ?1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$q = $qb->update('Organization\Entity\OrgMapping', 'om')
        ->set('om.active', $qb->expr()->literal($isActive))     
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->orX(    
                $qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->eq('om.organization', '?1')
                    ,
                    $qb->expr()->eq('om.serviceProvider','?2')
                ),
                $qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->eq('om.organization', '?2')
                    ,
                    $qb->expr()->eq('om.serviceProvider','?1')
                )
            )
        )
        ->setParameter(1, $organizationId)
        ->setParameter(2, $hspId)
        ->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* do it.

If you do an UPDATE query, you're missing the whole point of using Doctrine, that is mapping objects to database rows, not just an abstraction to queries.

Instead, extract your objects, then do a cycle and perform actions on single objects, then flush after the cycle.

Comment: By some cases it can be justified. It's OK, so long the dev knows what he does.